# how to use PCRE match in access_log path

Tags: nginx

I read this article http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule and it seems that this is possible. I'd like to do something like what I have in the config directives below but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone provide some guidance?

```
location ~ /foo/(.*) {
    access_log /var/log/$1.access.log;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that you should keep in mind, probably you must already be knowing all of them ;).

1. Nginx has ***one parent process (MASTER PROCESS)*** which always runs as **root**.
2. The default logs are created (if it doesn't exists) when nginx gets **started/restarted/reloaded** and also by **root user**.
3. So it is obvious that the owner of /var/log/nginx is root.

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug 14 01:35 nginx/
   ```

   or to generalize, the owner for /var/log is also root, and only root can write in it.
4. Any request is processed by **THE WORKER PROCESS** ( owned & run by 'nginx/nobody' user), ***not by*** the  **THE MASTER PROCESS** ( owned & run by 'root' user).

   If no nginx user is there then worker processes run by user **nobody***.

   ```
   root      1272  0.0  0.1  12080  3932 ?        Ss   00:27   0:00 nginx: master process         /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   nobody    4226  0.0  0.0  12240  2236 ?        S    01:43   0:00 nginx: worker process
   ```
5. And in this scenario **while processing the location block** if it comes to write a log in /var/log/nginx it will get permission error **:'(** (as its nginx or nobody user, which is not having permission to write in this directory).

   This is also applicable for the case the log is in /var/log

   ```
   2013/08/14 02:00:39 [crit] 4226#0: *20 open() "/var/log/nginx/adad?qwerty.access.log" failed (13: Permission denied) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /adad?qwerty HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
   ```

   in the above example i was writing log as

   ```
   access_log /var/log/nginx/$request_uri.access.log;
   ```

   which obviously got failed.

So to make things working, follow this way.

1. create a user for nginx, its advised as --

   ```
   useradd -s /sbin/nologin -M nginx
   ```
2. Update you nginx config /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ( add this in the first line of this config) and the reload it (service nginx reload)

   ```
   user    nginx;
   ```

   Now all the worker process (child process) will run as user - 'nginx'
3. Make a common directory for keeping logs say /var/log/**nginx/** and update the nginx config to point to this location.

   Make a nginx reload after this.
4. And Now the most important thing, **Make this directory owned by nginx user.**

   ```
   chown -R nginx:nginx /var/log/nginx
   ```
5. *Finally, you can use the  @VBART's method in location block.*

And if something goes wrong, please enable the error_log in debug mode, and it will tell you  problems if any.

And also considering the @TroyCheng's comment below,

And if you have **started you nginx service**  i.e. The master process, from some other user say 'work' or (nginx from my case) , then all the child process will also run from that privileges, and in that scenario you will have to (tough to start the process you must have already done this) allow this user to write logs in the logging directory say /var/log/nginx

Comment: Nice answer, but it's better not to run nginx using ROOT, especially in production environment.  'user' directive only works when nginx is started by ROOT. When using other account such as 'work' to start, the worker process will also be owned by 'work'.

Comment: @TroyCheg: Thankyou so much to point that out. I totally agree with you. So in any case that 'work' user should have write privs on /var/log/nginx folder (or any logging folder/location).

Comment: There is no security risk to start nginx master process using `root` since it doesn't process requests at all. But if you start it using the same user as for the worker processes, then your configuration will be readable by these workers, which is not good.

Answer (score 2):

Your positional capture (`$1`) doesn't exist on the log phase. You should use named captures instead.

```
location ~ /foo/(?<mylog>.*) {
    access_log /var/log/$mylog.access.log;
}
```

Comment: This is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $1 here does not what you want. Be careful regex in location directive only works for url matching, it do not extract any variables so you can not use $x to get the match value  from location directive.

This should work:

```
location ~ /foo/(.*) {
    access_log /var/log/foo.access.log; //you can add [log_format] at last;
}
```